# VHDL Code Help -Break integer into pieces

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I have this codepiece

```
Process(counter)
begin
case counter is
when 0 => countertonumber <= "11000000";  -- 0
when 1 => countertonumber <= "11111001" ; -- 1
when 2 => countertonumber <= "10100100" ; -- 2
when 3 => countertonumber <= "10110000" ; -- 3
when 4 => countertonumber <= "10011001" ; -- 4
when 5 => countertonumber <= "10010010" ; -- 5
when 6 => countertonumber <= "10000011" ; -- 6
when 7 => countertonumber <= "11111000" ; -- 7
when 8 => countertonumber <= "10000000" ; -- 8
when 9 => countertonumber <= "10010000" ; -- 9  
when others => 
end case;
end process;
```

This code piece is essential for my program to work (displaying numbers on 4*7 segment diplay).   The problem is the Integer value of Counter goes from 0 - 9999, i would rather not Write all 9999 posibilities.
Would it be possible to check each integer, and thereby  use it  check what value it should write to the pins.

Like if counter = 9999, 
then i could have switch case for each value, in my counter value..

I am bit lost on how i can effectively do it in VHDL...

Complete code and my idea.

```
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Company: 
-- Engineer: 
-- 
-- Create Date:    23:52:28 03/05/2014 
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    Main - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;




entity Main is
PORT(
        CLK: in std_logic;
    --  LED: out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
        Switch: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        Segment: out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0); 
        AN: out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) 
        );
end Main;


architecture Behavioral of Main is
signal counter_1000:     integer range 0 to 10;
signal counter_100:          integer range 0 to 10;
signal counter_10:       integer range 0 to 10;
signal counter_1:            integer range 0 to 10;
signal prescaler:  integer range 0 to 50000000;
signal limit:        integer range 0 to 50000000;
signal countertonumber: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

begin
ScalerChoice: Process(switch)
begin
CASE Switch IS
when "00000001" => limit <= 50000000/1; -- 1 Hz;
when "00000010" => limit <= 50000000/3; -- 3 HZ
When "00000100" => limit <= 50000000/10; -- 10 Hz
when "00001000" => limit <= 50000000/25; -- 25 Hz
When "00010000" => limit <= 50000000/50; -- 50 Hz; 
when "00100000" => limit <= 50000000/100; -- 100 hz
when others => limit <=      50000000/50000000; -- 50 MHz
end case;
end process;

CounterProcess: process(CLK,Switch)
begin
if rising_edge(CLK) then
    if prescaler < limit then 
        prescaler <= prescaler + 1;
        else
            prescaler <= 0; 
            counter_1 <= counter_1 + 1;

                if (counter_1 > 9) then
                counter_1 <= 0;
                counter_10 <= counter_10 + 1;

                    if (counter_10 > 9) then
                    counter_10 <= 0;
                    counter_100 <= counter_100 + 1;

                        if (counter_100 > 9) then
                        counter_100 <= 0;
                        counter_1000 <= counter_1000 + 1;

                            if (counter_1000 > 9) then
                            counter_100 <= 0;
                            counter_10 <= 0;
                            counter_1 <= 0;
                            counter_1000 <= 0;
                            end if;
                        end if;
                    end if;
                end if; 
        end if;
end if;
end process;


Process(counter_1, Counter_10,Counter_100,Counter_1000,clk)
begin
if rising_edge(cLK) then
    An <= "1110";
    case counter_1 is
    when 0 => countertonumber <= "11000000";  -- 0
    when 1 => countertonumber <= "11111001" ; -- 1
    when 2 => countertonumber <= "10100100" ; -- 2
    when 3 => countertonumber <= "10110000" ; -- 3
    when 4 => countertonumber <= "10011001" ; -- 4
    when 5 => countertonumber <= "10010010" ; -- 5
    when 6 => countertonumber <= "10000011" ; -- 6
    when 7 => countertonumber <= "11111000" ; -- 7
    when 8 => countertonumber <= "10000000" ; -- 8
    when others => countertonumber <= "11000000" ; -- 9 
    end case;

    case counter_10 is
    when 0 => countertonumber <= "11000000";  -- 0
    when 1 => countertonumber <= "11111001" ; -- 1
    when 2 => countertonumber <= "10100100" ; -- 2
    when 3 => countertonumber <= "10110000" ; -- 3
    when 4 => countertonumber <= "10011001" ; -- 4
    when 5 => countertonumber <= "10010010" ; -- 5
    when 6 => countertonumber <= "10000011" ; -- 6
    when 7 => countertonumber <= "11111000" ; -- 7
    when 8 => countertonumber <= "10000000" ; -- 8
    when others => countertonumber <= "11000000" ; -- 9 
    end case;
    segment <= countertonumber;


    An <= "1011";
    case counter_100 is
    when 0 => countertonumber <= "11000000";  -- 0
    when 1 => countertonumber <= "11111001" ; -- 1
    when 2 => countertonumber <= "10100100" ; -- 2
    when 3 => countertonumber <= "10110000" ; -- 3
    when 4 => countertonumber <= "10011001" ; -- 4
    when 5 => countertonumber <= "10010010" ; -- 5
    when 6 => countertonumber <= "10000011" ; -- 6
    when 7 => countertonumber <= "11111000" ; -- 7
    when 8 => countertonumber <= "10000000" ; -- 8
    when others => countertonumber <= "11000000" ; -- 9 
    end case;
    segment <= countertonumber;


    An <= "0111";
    case counter_1000 is
    when 0 => countertonumber <= "11000000";  -- 0
    when 1 => countertonumber <= "11111001" ; -- 1
    when 2 => countertonumber <= "10100100" ; -- 2
    when 3 => countertonumber <= "10110000" ; -- 3
    when 4 => countertonumber <= "10011001" ; -- 4
    when 5 => countertonumber <= "10010010" ; -- 5
    when 6 => countertonumber <= "10000011" ; -- 6
    when 7 => countertonumber <= "11111000" ; -- 7
    when 8 => countertonumber <= "10000000" ; -- 8
    when others => countertonumber <= "11000000" ; -- 9 

    segment <= countertonumber;
    end case;
end if;
end process;



end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Separate your separate hardware.  My recommend is that your prescaler goes in a separate entity.  This will allow you to do interesting things in simulation - like run it much faster so that you can run your clock through all of its states/values in a reasonable amount of simulation time.

Comment: The full code will fail to simulate when counter_1 (etc) are asssigned values outside the valid range.

Comment: I've done that..  but how should i proceed???

Comment: how can it be outside range??

Comment: If counter_1 never goes out of range, then `counter_1 > 9` will never be true, which would allow a lot of redundant logic to be trimmed...

Comment: Well.. that is easy to change, just change the integer range to go from 0 to 10?

Problem is though it only displays on the last segment, and not on the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have multiple assignment for counters in the same CLK edge, plus counter declared in range 0-9 can't be tested to be more then 9. This is your process a little bit revisited. I have not tested but I suppose it make your task.

```
   CounterProcess: process(CLK,Switch)
   begin
      if rising_edge(CLK) then
         if prescaler < limit then
            prescaler <= prescaler + 1;
         else
            prescaler <= 0;
            if (counter_1 < 9) then
               counter_1 <= counter_1 + 1;
            else
               counter_1 <= 0;
               if (counter_10 < 9) then
                  counter_10 <= counter_10 + 1;
               else
                  counter_10 <= 0;
                  if (counter_100 < 9) then
                     counter_100 <= counter_100 + 1;
                  else
                     counter_100 <= 0;
                     if (counter_1000 < 9) then
                        counter_1000 <= counter_100 + 1;
                     else
                        counter_1000 <= 0;
                        counter_1    <= 0;
                        counter_10   <= 0;
                        counter_100  <= 0;
                     end if;
                  end if;
               end if;
            end if;
         end if;
      end if;
   end process;

enter code here
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Won't each one increment since they all are less than nine from the beginning?

Comment: No, it run just up to the first counter less then 9 and exit because else.
At the beginning it only increment counter_1 and exit.

Answer (score 1):

**For any hardware problem, start by drawing the picture of the hardware first, then write code.**

I see the following in your code, only one anode is selected at a time and the digits are multiplexed onto the cathode lines.  What I don't see clearly captured in your code is how you are picking a particular anode and counter(i).  Based on your "idea" code, the last assignment wins and you end up selecting counter(3) and AN <= "1110"; always.

What I recommend is that you break this part of your problem down into two pieces.  The first piece selects the which anode and which counter is selected.  The second piece decodes the active counter and places that value on cathodes (countertonumber).  If you do it this way, you only need to write (and debug) one case statement for decoding the counters.

The piece you are missing is the selection of the anode and active counter.  I have used an additional counter to do this.  On a perfect board, counting 0 to 3 would work fine.  On the boards I have used, the transistors connected to the anodes were slow, so I used values 0 to 7.  Value 0, anode 0 is on and Counter(0) is the active counter.  Value 1, all anodes off and Counter(0) is the active counter.  Value 1, anode 1 is on and Counter(1) is the active counter.  Value 2, all anodes off and Counter (1) is the active counter.  And so on.

Your code for decoding the active counter is simply the code you wrote above.

If use multiple processes, use a signal for the active counter value.  If you use a single process, use a variable for the active counter value.

Comment: I edited my question to include the complete code. 
As you can see i Counter has 4 stages  (thousand,hundred,tens , ones)
but as you mention i have some problems switching between the anode. 
I thought i could do a left shift, but realized it's impossible to do :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about performance, you could consider keeping your count value in 4 separate digits which count from 0 to 9, instead of unsing a single, large integer. You could use variables or signals for that purpose. When one of the individual digits overflows, you should increment the next one. To generate the displays output, you would simply replicate the same conversion logic for each digit. You can use a function or a separate entity for that, to avoid duplicating code.

If you are not that worried about performance, you may take a look at a small library I wrote. Check the answer to [Decimal number on 7 segment display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866747/decimal-number-on-7-segment-display/20870852).

Comment: My  question is not about the perfomance, but just the ability to break it down to pieces. so 9999 will be breaken down to 4 pieces of 9 9 9 9. And using that i could lid each 7 segment using code..  Look at the edit to see my how i want my to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this depends on the representation of your counter value.

If it is represented as an array of 4 decimal digits, (i.e. using BCD arithmetic) then you simply treat each digit in turn.

Even if your counter is binary, you will find that division by 10 and computing the remainder is not an impossibly expensive operation; especially if you don't need the result in a single clock cycle : a state machine performing repeated subtraction will only take 10 clock cycles per digit. And at the rate you are updating a display I doubt that sort of delay matters!

I would use a constant array for my display decoding values and replace each of those huge case statements with a simple lookup in the array.

For example:

```
type Count_Value is natural range 0 to 9999;
type Digit is natural range 0 to 9;
type Digits is (thousands, hundreds, tens, units);
type Display_Data is std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

constant Divisors : array (Digits) of Count_Value := (1000, 100, 10, 1);
constant Lookup   : array (Digit) of Display_Data := 
                    ("11000000", "11111001", ... 10010000");

signal Display : array(Digits) of Display_Data;
signal Count : Count_Value;
signal Start : std_logic;

...

Update : process (Clock) is
   type     State_Type is (idle, processing);
   variable State : State_Type;
   variable This_Digit : Digits;
   variable This_Value : Digit;
   variable Remaining  : Count_Value;
begin
   if rising_edge(Clock) then
      if State = idle then   -- convert when asked
         if Start = '1' then
            Remaining  := Count;
            This_Digit := thousands;
            This_Value := 0;
            State      := processing;
         end if;
      else
         -- process current digit
         if Remaining < Divisors(This_Digit) then
            -- finish this digit
            Display(This_Digit) <= Lookup(This_Value);
            -- done?
            if This_Digit = Units then
               State := idle;
            else
               -- move to next digit
               This_Value := 0;
               This_Digit := Digits'succ(This_Digit);
            end if;            
         else
            Remaining  := Remaining - Divisors(This_Digit);
            This_Value := This_Value + 1;
         end if;
      end if; 
   end if;
end process;
```

EDIT: This example is a process which, when Start is asserted, will divide an integer Count into four separate digits, and output the 7-segment decode values for those digits onto the `Display` signal. It could easily be adapted to drive a multiplexed display instead, or to add functionality such as a signal to indicate when it has completed generating the display values.

I'll leave optional features such as leading-zero blanking, or avoiding re-triggering if Start is still high after processing has finished as an exercise.

Comment: I must say i have a hard time understanding your code.. All your type declarations..

I know my solution may suck since, i just copy paste 4 times, but wouldn't i work or how do i make it work?

Comment: What's difficult to understand about them? They are all basic stuff. I'm not being funny, if you can identify what's difficult I can explain it. Each of your Case statements is equivalent to `countertonumber <= Lookup(counter(x));` and your approach CAN be made to work IF the counter is using BCD arithmetic.

Comment: youre whole process. I mean I don't see how it's even going to trigger anything??